# Array in this.props (provided by redux) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I fetch data via Redux in my component like so:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from './../../_actions/actionCreators';

import './Posts.css';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {posts: state.posts, comments: state.comments}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>POSTS</h1>

        {
          console.log(this.props)
        }


      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts);
```

This code is working and will put out the following JSON in the console: [JSON output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaJhS.png)

When trying to log `this.props` or `this.props.posts` everything returns just fine.
But when trying to log `this.props.posts.allposts` the console returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns json with multiple values then you need to do it as

```
return(
<div>
{
this.props.posts.allposts(function(allposts,i)
{
return <h1 key={i}>{allposts}</h1>


})
}
</div>
```